# Strava API Request Issues in Swift

Tags: swift, strava

I'm working to access Strava api endpoints with my iOS Swift 5 app using Alamofire.  I'm able to authenticate and get an OAuth token, but when I try to make GET requests, an error is returned saying:

```
{
errors =     (
            {
        code = invalid;
        field = "access_token";
        resource = Athlete;
    }
);
message = "Authorization Error";
}
```

What am I doing wrong with the GET requests?  Below is my function for trying to get an athlete's heart rate and power zones from the [zones endpoint](http://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Athletes-getLoggedInAthleteZones):

```
func getTimeInZones(athleteID: String, completion: @escaping ([String]?) -> Void) {
        // 1
        print("The token: \(strava.token)")
        Alamofire.request("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/zones",
                          method: .get,
                          parameters: ["athlete": athleteID],
                          headers: ["Authorization": "Bearer \(strava.token)"])
            // 2
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess,
                    let value = response.result.value else {
                        print("Error while fetching zones: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                        completion(nil)
                        return
                }
                print(value)

                // 3
                let zones = JSON(value)["results"][0]["zones"].array?.map { json in
                    json["zone"].stringValue
                }



                // 4
                completion(zones)
        }
    }
```

The zones endpoint has min, max, and time spent in an athlete's heart rate and power zones during endurance training.  So I want this function to return a json array of an athlete's heart rate and power zones and the time spent in each zone.

Comment: So obviously Strava considers the token you're passing as invalid. Are you sure `strava.token` is exactly what you got back from your authentication requests? What's the value being printed?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Gereon.  I checked as you suggested, and it looks like the token is correct because the value printed is the same as the value that works with another part of my code where I use a swift wrapper for the Strava api called "StravaSwift" to get an athlete's basic stats.  I think the issue might be that I'm using a token that has a limited "read" authorization, and I need a new token that has a "read_all" auth.  I modified the auth request to read_all, but how would I deauthorize/refresh the token in this case?

Comment: are you sure to be authorized for "Athlete" queries? Strava services are available via a subscription, maybe the user did not pay for that service

Comment: @JerettGordon during the initial authorisation, the user would be presented w/ options to allow for Read or write authorisation. Did you put this as part of the request in StravaSwift?